# PHP connetion to mysql server database

Tags: php, mysql

I just want to test db connection from my browser. But i get empty page. I am not getting Error message.

```
<?php

    $con =  mysqli_connect('http://ec2-54-67-69-153.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/', 'root', 'root') or die(mysqli_error($con));

    if ($con) {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "fail";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Did you tried with: `localhost` as host? Also maybe you want a 4th argument with db name

Comment: `mysqli_connect` doesn't take a URL as a connection. Use just the hostname. Additionally, we need to know where your database is, where your PHP is actually being run, and some details of your networking setup (e.g. if you're *inside* an EC2 VPC, i.e. both the PHP server and the database server are there, you probably don't want to use the *public* IP address/name of the database to connect.) You also need to make sure you're opened up the firewall for MySQL both on the instance itself, and for that instance's security policy in AWS, if you're trying to connect from outside.

Comment: yaa localhost works fine in my pc. But i host ubuntu server on amazon.

Comment: so i have to give public ip ?

Comment: Also, Check if you have all the necessary includes (none are visible in your code). For example include('mysql.dbi.lib.php');

Comment: can u pls tell where to include that. but db is connected successfully on my localhost without those include files

Comment: try this without http 'ec2-54-67-69-153.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com'

Comment: Your error is
, Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: i tried without http. i also tried using ip

Comment: Am i enable some permission for clients to access db? i am newbie. pls help

Comment: is your PHPmyadmin working from Cpannel?

Comment: @Matt Gibson yaa i use aws ec2. i already open up all inbound and outbound connections. sry for late reply(suddenly my internet connection is not working)

Comment: @zeeshan i don't use phpmyadmin. i use mysql from command line. i hosted server in amazon web service. sry for late reply.

Comment: @RajagopalSubramanian may be you have to contact with your hosting provider

Answer (score 0):

```
**Here is a handy function that connects you to a Database, using *Object Oriented* style:**
function MySQLi_quickConnect()
{
  $host     = 'somewebsite.db.120327161.hostedresource.com'; //or 'http://localhost'
  $username = '<YOUR USERNAME>';
  $password = '<YOUR PASSWORD>';
  $database = '<YOUR DATABASES NAME>';

  $db = new MySQLi($host,$username,$password,$database);
  $error_message = $db->connect_error;
  if($error_message != NULL){die("Error:" . $error_message . "<br>" . "Occured in function
                                         MySQLi_quickConnect");}
  return $db;   
}

**A simple example on how you would query the Database:**
$db = MySQLi_quickConnect(); //this is your new Database object
$sql = "<YOUR SQL STATEMENT>"; 
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
if(!$stmt){die('MyError : ('. $db->errno .') '. $db->error);}  //kill script, show errors
```